# Warning: BRK.B download failed; trying again. [Quantmod] R package

Tags: r, quantmod

I have ran into an error when trying to download a list of symbols using the quantmod package.

I have the following;

```
startdate <- "2017-11-05"
enddate <- "2018-01-20"

    Symbols <- c("XOM","MSFT","JNJ", "BRK.B","GE","CVX","WFC","PG","JPM","VZ","PFE","T","IBM","MRK","BAC","DIS","ORCL","PM","INTC","SLB")



    dailyreturns = lapply(Symbols, function(sym) {
      dailyReturn(na.omit(getSymbols(sym, from= startdate, to = enddate, auto.assign=FALSE, src = "yahoo")))
    })
```

Which returns the following error message;

```
Warning: BRK.B download failed; trying again.
```

I have tried to use `complete cases` and other methods to skip failed download data but still this error persists

```
Warning: BRK.B download failed; trying again.
Error: BRK.B download failed after two attempts. Error message:
HTTP error 404.
Called from: getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "BRK.B", env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE, 
    warnings = TRUE, auto.assign = FALSE, from = "2017-11-05", 
    to = "2018-01-20")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aparantly it could be due to the following: https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/202

Comment: Okay fixed, I believe that it was a problem due to the some of the variables having a fullstop in them such as "BRK.B" and they were not able to be read through, eliminating them solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem, the reason is that it's not `BRK.B`, it is `BRK-B`. Usually, R converts `-` to `.` for column names when reading from a .csv file if `check.names = TRUE`.